# java.lang.NullPointerException at com.sun.faces.application.annotation.ManagedBeanConfigHandler.collectAnnotatedFields

Tags: jsf, annotations, managed-bean

When I add `@ManagedBean` annotation to my `ItemService` class, the following error occurs:

```
SEVERE: Critical error during deployment: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:377)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4992)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.annotation.ManagedBeanConfigHandler.collectAnnotatedFields(ManagedBeanConfigHandler.java:246)
    at com.sun.faces.application.annotation.ManagedBeanConfigHandler.collectAnnotatedFields(ManagedBeanConfigHandler.java:263)
    at com.sun.faces.application.annotation.ManagedBeanConfigHandler.getBeanInfo(ManagedBeanConfigHandler.java:155)
    at com.sun.faces.application.annotation.ManagedBeanConfigHandler.process(ManagedBeanConfigHandler.java:141)
    at com.sun.faces.application.annotation.ManagedBeanConfigHandler.push(ManagedBeanConfigHandler.java:127)
    at com.sun.faces.application.annotation.AnnotationManager.applyConfigAnnotations(AnnotationManager.java:200)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.processAnnotations(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:326)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ManagedBeanConfigProcessor.process(ManagedBeanConfigProcessor.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ValidatorConfigProcessor.process(ValidatorConfigProcessor.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ConverterConfigProcessor.process(ConverterConfigProcessor.java:126)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ComponentConfigProcessor.process(ComponentConfigProcessor.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.process(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:340)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:222)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:362)
    ... 10 more
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Telling the exact Mojarra version would be helpful so that one can just look in source code for answer based on line numbers in stack trace.

Comment: Initializing Mojarra 2.1.13 ( 20120907-1514)